# hasClass() jquery works just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, scroll, menu

this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('#first-item').hasClass('active'){
        $( ".go-prev" ).addClass( "hideMe" );
    } else {
        $( ".go-prev" ).removeClass( "hideMe" );
    }
})
```

this code works just once and when I scroll to next page (slide) it does not remove the active class
whats the solution

Comment: No where in your code do you tell jQuery to remove the `active` class. Also, `hasClass('.active')` should be `hasClass('active')`

Comment: dear @Spectric, yea I removed the dot(.) but did not work
active class changes by scroll
I also edited the code here

Comment: You only call the function once when the document first loads. Did you mean to have this run on scroll?

Comment: @Samathingamajig | on mouse wheel on page or clicking on next and prev buttons, the page will change to up and down. I'm using fullpage js

Comment: Post the entire file please

Comment: This runs only when the page finishes loading,after that nothing will trigger this block of code again.if you want it to run everytime the active class is added or removed at a specific element,you can listen to a MutationObserver on that element and run this code,preferably using a reuseable function

Comment: @Vaggelis | so what should the code be like?

Comment: posted a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment :

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  //we define our observed element
  const observedElement = document.getElementById("first-item");
  //we create an observer and pass a callback function..
  new MutationObserver(mutationCallback)
    //and we set it to observe,a specific element's mutations
    .observe(observedElement, {
      attributes: true,
      attributeFilter: ["class"],
    });
  //it will run the callback function everytime it detects a mutation on the observed element..
  //such as change of classlist items etc..
});

const mutationCallback = () => {
  if ($("#first-item").hasClass("active")) {
    $(".go-prev").addClass("hideMe");
  } else {
    $(".go-prev").removeClass("hideMe");
  }
};

//lets make a mutation to observed element to see if it works
const testMutation = () => {
  $("#first-item").addClass("active");
}
```

```css
.hideMe{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="first-item">OBSERVED ELEMENT</h1>
<h1 class="go-prev">AFFECTED ELEMENT</h1>
<button onclick="testMutation()">TEST</button>
```

Learn more about [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)